Is it possible to get the default texture or UVs from a fragment shader in Flutter?
I know shaders in flutter are a relatively new thing, which is why I can't find that much good documentation online. I'm wondering if there's a way to get access to the default texture uniform or UVs in a fragment shader attached to a paint for canvas calls like drawImage or drawAtlas. I know I can pass the image as a my own uniform, and any additional data needed to calculate the UVs, but it would be a lot more convenient, especially for drawAtlas, to have that sort of data from some default set of values.
Also shaders on canvas calls that draw images don't seem to work, so maybe it's just not supported right now.
Hopefully that makes sense.

you can try   vec2 uv = FlutterFragCoord() / u_size; texture(u_grid, uv).r
